# Match the words using re compile in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, nlp, regex-negation

I'm new to Python, i have text file which consists of punctuation and other words how to recompile using specific text match.

text file looks like below **actual with more that 100 sentences like below**

**file.txt**

```
copy() {
foundation.d.k("cloud control")
this.is.a(context),reality, new point {"copy.control.ZOOM_CONTROL", "copy.control.ACTIVITY_CONTROL"},
context control
```

I just want the output something like this

```
copy.control.ZOOM_CONTROL
copy.control.ACTIVITY_CONTROL
```

i coded something like this

```
file=(./data/.txt)
data=re.compile('copy.control. (.*?)', re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE).findall(file)
res= str("|".join(data))
```

The above regex doesn't match for my required output. please help me on this issue. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open and read the file first, then apply the `re.findall` method:

```
data = []
with open('./data/.txt', 'r') as file:
  data = re.findall(r'\bcopy\.control\.(\w+)', file.read())
```

The `\bcopy\.control\.(\w+)` regex matches

- `\bcopy\.control\.` - a `copy.control.` string as a whole word (`\b` is a word boundary)
- `(\w+)` - Capturing group 1 (the output of `re.findall`): 1 or more letters, digits or `_`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J7x8yu/1).

Then, you may print the matches:

```
for m in data:
  print(m)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution if i dont want the repeated one means can i use re.search?

Comment: @DarshanMahalingeGowda `re.search` will return the first occurrence only. If you want to remove duplicate matches, use `set`, `print(list(set(data)))`